# Adding an alert to a <td> with an onclick event handler

Tags: javascript, html

I have a 10 by 10 HTML table on my page that represents a game. I am currently trying to make the game grid clickable, but for some reason my onclick handler is not working properly. For testing purposes, I just want to display an alert when the user clicks inside one of the grid cells, but I can't seem to get it to work.

This is the code I have:

```
<body>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var compDiv = document.getElementById("computer");
        var compCells = compDiv.getElementsByTagName("td");

        for (var i = 0; i < compCells.length; i++) {
            compCells[i].onclick = alertUser;
        }

        function alertUser() {
            alert("HI");
        }
   </script>
</body>
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE FIXED**

I'm not sure what was going on but when I put the above code inside a function and called that function with onload in my `<body>` tag, it worked. It's now displaying as it should. :)

Comment: Where is it located in the page source? i.e. in the `head` tag or at the bottom, below the table?

Comment: Maybe you have to define alerUser function before using it? At the point you refer to it, it is undefined.

Comment: Wrap your code in `DOMContentLoaded` or place your script right before closing `</body>` tag..

Comment: @LuanNico, In `function declaration`, order does not matter...

Comment: Right now i had the script after the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: put it inside closing body tag, not outside

Comment: @WitchKing17,There is something else which is causing issues... It is working fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/f9bvxj9a/

Comment: @charlietfl @RayonDabre I have put it inside the closing body tag, but it still isn't working. Is it because I don't have a `this` anywhere? Ex: `this.alert`

Comment: Are any errors thrown in browser console?

Comment: @charlieftl For some reason it thinks my table is null. It can't find my table. I did this exact same function in another test page, like Rayon Dabre did, and it worked just fine, so something is wrong with my page. I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: @RayonDabre I couldn't get DOMContentLoaded to work, but onload essentially does the same thing. I just had to put the above code into my onload in my `<body>` and it is now working. Thanks for that tip. It helped me figure it out.

Comment: @WitchKing17, Glad to help...Good time!

Comment: @Rayon , All comments come to the same point. The way jsfiddle is making the HTML with provided JS , will lead to something which is causing the issue.